Computing primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$
The book Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$ by Cox discusses in detail the problem of when a prime $p$ can be written as $x^2+ny^2$, and along the way introduces more and more sophisticated number theory such as reciprocity laws, class field theory, elliptic curves and modular functions.
A few classical results are:
$p=x^2+y^2\Longleftrightarrow p=1\text{ mod }4$
$p=x^2+2y^2\Longleftrightarrow p=1,3\text{ mod }8$
$p=x^2+5y^2\Longleftrightarrow p=1,9\text{ mod }20$
But then something more complicated shows up:
$p=x^2+27y^2\Longleftrightarrow p=1\text{ mod }3$ and $x^3-2$ has a root mod $p$
The main theorem of the book is:

Let $n>0$. There is a monic irreducible polynomial $f_n(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that for any odd prime $p$ that divides neither $n$ nor the discriminant of $f_n(x):$
$p=x^2+ny^2\Longleftrightarrow \left(\dfrac{-n}{p}\right)=1$ and $f_n(x)$ has a root mod $p$

Question 1: Suppose $n$ is fixed and we already know $f_n(x)$. In terms of determining whether a given prime $p$ can be written as $x^2+ny^2$, how efficient is this method compared to more direct methods, like exhausting all $y\leq\sqrt{p/n}$ and checking whether $p-ny^2$ is a perfect square? I guess $\left(\frac{-n}{p}\right)$ can be calculated efficiently using quadratic reciprocity, but what about checking if $f_n(x)$ has a root mod $p$? That sounds harder than checking if $p$ is $1$ or $9$ mod $20$.
Question 2: The construction of $f_n(x)$ given $n$ looks quite complicated. So if the input is a pair $(p,n)$ and we want to determine if $p=x^2+ny^2$, is the above theorem still more efficient than direct methods?

What you actually do  is   to construct a form $au^2 + b uv + c v^2 = p,$    where $b^2 - 4ac = -4n.$  Then Gauss reduction of that form, with some extra record keeping, tells you what reduced form represents $p$  There is more to say, let me look up somethings

Let's start with $n$ odd.
Alright, you want even discriminant  $-4n$ First   you find, using an algorithm   due to Cornacchia, or one due to Tonelli-Shanks,  a solution $\beta$  to
$$   \beta^2 \equiv - n \pmod p.$$
If $\beta$ is even, let $b = \beta.$ If $\beta$ is odd, let
$b = p - \beta$  Now $b$ is even and
$$   b^2 \equiv - 4 n \pmod {4p}.$$
That is, there is integer $c$ with
$$   b^2 + 4 n = 4pc,$$
also
$$   b^2 -4pc = - 4 n .$$
That is, the form $p x^2 + b xy + cy^2 $   has discriminant $-4n.$  It represents $p$  with $x=1, y=0.$
At this point, we don't yet know which reduced form represents $p.$  Call $H$ the Hessian of second partials of $p x^2 + b xy + cy^2 .$   The Gauss reduction process constructs, one step at a time, a 2 by 2 integer matrix $P$   where $P^T H P= G,$   where $G$ is the Hessian of a reduced form. Naming $Q = P^{-1} ,$     we have $Q^T G Q = H$ The left hand column of $Q$  is the representation of $p$  by the form with Hessian $G.$   If this is the principal form, you win. If not, you have a representation by some other (reduced) form of that discriminant.

I'm not familiar with quadratic forms---so does your last sentence mean what you described is not really an algorithm for the original question?

@newaccount no, it is. If all you know is a Legendre symbol saying that  $p$  is represented by some form of discriminant $-4n,$  this method tells you which form that is.  In your $x^3 - 2$   example, if you have a prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$  then it is represented by $x^2 + 3 y^2.$  If you run my method with discriminant $-108$  it will either tell you $p = x^2 + 27 y^2$  with explicit $x,y,$   or tell you  $p = 4x^2 + 2xy + 7 y^2, $ meaning $x^2 + 27 y^2$  is impossible

Can you say a bit about the significance of Cox's theorem if it is not computationally advantageous?

@newaccount  let's turn it around. Why are you reading Cox if you are uncomfortable with quadratic forms?

Well, I was hoping to find some applications of class field theory to concrete problems so that I may feel motivated to learn it. I'm not familiar with quadratic forms but they do seem cool, more so than class field theory.

There are a few books now that develop quadratic fields and quadratic forms side by side. Sort of a gentle beginning for algebraic number theory.  One by J. L. Lehman, called Quadratic Number Theory. One by M. Trifkovic called Algebraic Theory of Quadratic Numbers.
